# Consistent Social Media Buttons

Tags: html, css, social-media

I am building a website that has the usual social media links in a footer on my page:

[image: Set of social media buttons]

They are hosted in an HTML element coded as:

```html
        <div class="social">
     <table>
          <tr>
              <td><a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>
                  <div 
                      class="fb-like"
                      data-href="@Context.Request.Scheme://@Context.Request.Host.ToString()@Context.Request.PathBase@Context.Request.Path"
                      data-layout="button"
                      data-action="like"
                      data-show-faces="true">
                  </div>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td>
                  <script type="IN/Share" data-counter="right">
                  </script>&nbsp;
              </td>
              <td><a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark"><img alt="Pin it" src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" border="0" /></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
</div>
```

How can I force the alignment or padding of the buttons to be consistent?

Alternatively, if I want to use my own icons and hide these is there a standard approach to doing that?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: If you want to use your own icons please take a look at this article:  https://jonsuh.com/blog/social-share-links/

Answer (score 1):

The way this is constructed is wrong! Please use table for data and not for styling. Change it to a div and you'll find that making it mobile responsive is easy.

Try to nest the divs so you can just move your main div and all the sub-divs within it moves along.

Try something like this:

```css
.social { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div id="social-icons">

  <div class="social"><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/25/"></a></div>
  <div class="social"><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/25/"></a></div>
  <div class="social"><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/25/"></a></div>
  <div class="social"><a href="#"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/25/"></a></div>
  
</div>
```

And to make changes when viewing from a smaller screen - eg; mobile, then use `media queries` to align the content when a certain device size is reached.

Media Query CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .social {
         display: block;
         width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Of course, change the css styling to whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use flex instead of a table layout. Set the parent element to `display: flex;` and `align-items: top;`. That forces the direct children of `.social` to align at the top.

```css
.social {
  display: flex;
  align-items: top;
}

.social a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
 <div class="social">
    <a href="#">Facebook</a>
    <a href="#">Instagram</a>
    <a href="#">Pinterest</a>
    <a href="#">Twitter</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="social">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
                <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <a href="" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>&nbsp;</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <a href="" class="twitter-share-button">Like</a>&nbsp;</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <a href="" class="twitter-share-button">Share</a>&nbsp;</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <a href="" class="twitter-share-button">Save</a>&nbsp;</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```